# Laravel Method paginate does not exist trying controller

Tags: laravel, controller, pagination

```
$article = Article::all()->sortBy("order")->paginate(3);

return view('nieuws' , compact('article'));
```

wont work this is the error I get back:
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

Comment: I see so many question that show queries starting with `Model::all()`; **don't do this unless you need every row from your table**. Loading your entire table into memory can be incredibly inefficient, and there's a ton of methods that allow you to manipulate the query (Builder instance) before any data is returned (as a Collection).

Answer (score 2):

When you're using `all()` you get all the rows from the table and get a **collection**. You can only invoke `"paginate"` **on a Query**, **<s>not on a Collection</s>.** :

```
$article = Article::orderBy("order")->paginate(3);
```

<sup>There is no `sortBy()`  method on the query builder, it should be `orderBy`. You can only invoke `"sortBy"` **on a Collection**, **<s>not on a Query</s>**.</sup>

Comment: There is no `sortBy` method on the query builder, it should be `orderBy`